# Can't convert Core ML model to Onnx (then to Tensorflow Lite)

Tags: python, tensorflow, coreml, onnx

I'm trying to convert a trained Core ML model to TensorFlow Lite. I find I need convert it to Onnx first.

The problems is that I get errors. I've tried with different versions of python, onnxmltools, winmltools and it doesn't seems to work. I also tried docker image of onnx ecosystem with same result. Can any one help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Script I used:

```
import coremltools
import onnxmltools

input_coreml_model = '../model.mlmodel'
output_onnx_model = '../model.onnx'
coreml_model = coremltools.utils.load_spec(input_coreml_model)
onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_coreml(coreml_model)
onnxmltools.utils.save_model(onnx_model, output_onnx_model)
```

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-94a6dc527869> in <module>
      3 
      4 # Convert the CoreML model into ONNX
----> 5 onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_coreml(coreml_model)
      6 
      7 # Save as protobuf

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxmltools/convert/main.py in convert_coreml(model, name, initial_types, doc_string, target_opset, targeted_onnx, custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
     16     from .coreml.convert import convert
     17     return convert(model, name, initial_types, doc_string, target_opset, targeted_onnx,
---> 18                    custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
     19 
     20 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxmltools/convert/coreml/convert.py in convert(model, name, initial_types, doc_string, target_opset, targeted_onnx, custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
     58     target_opset = target_opset if target_opset else get_opset_number_from_onnx()
     59     # Parse CoreML model as our internal data structure (i.e., Topology)
---> 60     topology = parse_coreml(spec, initial_types, target_opset, custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
     61 
     62     # Parse CoreML description, author, and license. Those information will be attached to the final ONNX model.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxmltools/convert/coreml/_parse.py in parse_coreml(model, initial_types, target_opset, custom_conversion_functions, custom_shape_calculators)
    465     # Instead of using CoremlModelContainer, we directly pass the model in because _parse_model is CoreML-specific.
    466     _parse_model(topology, scope, model)
--> 467     topology.compile()
    468 
    469     for variable in topology.find_root_and_sink_variables():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxconverter_common/topology.py in compile(self)
    630         self._resolve_duplicates()
    631         self._fix_shapes()
--> 632         self._infer_all_types()
    633         self._check_structure()
    634 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxconverter_common/topology.py in _infer_all_types(self)
    506                 pass  # in Keras converter, the shape calculator can be optional.
    507             else:
--> 508                 operator.infer_types()
    509 
    510     def _resolve_duplicates(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxconverter_common/topology.py in infer_types(self)
    108     def infer_types(self):
    109         # Invoke a core inference function
--> 110         registration.get_shape_calculator(self.type)(self)
    111 
    112 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnxmltools/convert/coreml/shape_calculators/neural_network/Concat.py in calculate_concat_output_shapes(operator)
     22         if variable.type.shape[0] != 'None' and variable.type.shape[0] != output_shape[0]:
     23             raise RuntimeError('Only dimensions along C-axis can be different')
---> 24         if variable.type.shape[2] != 'None' and variable.type.shape[2] != output_shape[2]:
     25             raise RuntimeError('Only dimensions along C-axis can be different')
     26         if variable.type.shape[3] != 'None' and variable.type.shape[3] != output_shape[3]:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Yup, this is the kind of stuff that happens. It may be that your model does things that are not supported by ONNX, or that there is an issue with the converter tool. I usually end up solving such problems by writing a conversion script by hand. In this case you'd use coremltools to manually step through your Core ML model, and the flatbuffer API to write a new TFLite file.