# onnx_to_keras: "NotImplementedError: Can't modify this type of data"

Tags: python, deep-learning, onnx

I'm trying to import an onnx model and then convert it to Keras.

Below there is the snippet of code I use for saving the model in onnx format:

```
import onnxmltools

onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert_keras(model, model.name)
onnxmltools.utils.save_model(onnx_model, 'gdrive/My Drive/Model/RNN_comfort_model.onnx')
```

Below there is the snippet of code I use for import and conversion:

```
import onnx
import onnxmltools
from onnx2keras import onnx_to_keras

onnx_model = onnx.load('gdrive/My Drive/Model/RNN_comfort_model.onnx')
k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, ['lstm_5_input'], name_policy='renumerate')
```

When I run the last piece of code, I get

> NotImplementedError: Can't modify this type of data

The following screenshot describes the whole error:

[image: Click to see the screenshot]

I already checked that the input_names field is correct.

Comment: Can you provide the error in text format so that it is readable

Comment: ----> 6 k_model = onnx_to_keras(onnx_model, ['lstm_5_input'], name_policy='renumerate')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onnx2keras/reshape_layers.py in convert_transpose(node, params, layers, lambda_func, node_name, keras_name)
     25             layers[node_name] = np.transpose(layers[input_name], axes=params['perm'])
     26         else:
---> 27             raise NotImplementedError('Can\'t modify this type of data')
     28     else:
     29         permute = keras.layers.Permute(params['perm'][1:], name=keras_name)

NotImplementedError: Can't modify this type of data

Comment: According to the comments on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735629/cant-convert-core-ml-model-to-onnx-then-to-tensorflow-lite
This seems to be due to a model that has features not supported by onnx. However, i would suggest loading the model using `onnxtools.utils`, since that is what was used to save the model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but unfortunately that is not working either. I guess there is definitely a compatibility problem